# Querying against result of EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

My EXEC:

```
SET @Sql = "SELECT r.Id FROM Record r where r.Price > 100"
```

How do I query against the result of @Sql? Ideally something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Record r JOIN Patient p 
ON r.Id = p.recordId 
WHERE r.Id IN (EXEC(@Sql))
```

Comment: What is your actual purpose of using a dynamic query ?

Comment: Having many conditional WHERE clause. Don't look at the example, my real code has about 15-20 WHERE clauses, all conditional

Comment: But how does that justified the use of dynamic query ? Is dynamic query really necessary for your query here?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not the one who wrote the original query. I'm guessing what the original author wanted to do was: IF @param1 > 10, add this WHERE clause, else don't bother. I can try convert this to normal query if I know how to. I rarely ever need to touch stored proc codes, so I'm pretty noob at this.

Comment: Since you are using dynamic query, why don't you just form the complete query using dynamic sql ? rather than using temp table to store the intermediate result for subsequent query

Comment: I know I can use dynamic SQL, I'm curious if there are better ways. Is there any difference between writing the SQL dynamically or not?

Comment: A dynamic query `SELECT * FROM Record r JOIN Patient p ON r.Id = p.recordId where r.Price > 100` is definitely much better than the 2 step solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
SET @Sql = 'SELECT r.Id FROM Record r where r.Price > 100'

CREATE TABLE #DataSource 
(
    [ID] INT
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource ([ID])
EXEC(@SQL);

SELECT * 
FROM Record r 
JOIN Patient p 
    ON r.Id = p.recordId 
WHERE r.Id IN (SELECT [ID] FROM #DataSource);
```